# hook_menu for sitename.com/content-title

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to use sitename.com/content-title for one possibly two content types.

I can’t seem to add the correct wild card/token the menu hook.

> $items['%'] = array(
>   …
>   );

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) should do this for you. Use path rather than menu hooks for content as large menus cause perforance hits.

Comment: Thanks.  

I use pathauto but have always had an issue overriding the default node view for content. Ultimately I need to call my method that creates the html content for this specific node type.

Comment: That sounds like a theming issue. Try node-<node_type>.tpl.php

Comment: I could do that, I just try to avoid if possible and have pages defined in modules. Thanks again.